# Change tip labels in phylogeny in R

Tags: r, phylogeny

I have a `csv` file which consists of species names for several hundred species in the same order in which they appear in `$tip.labels` from my phylogeny. I want to swap out these species names with new species names such that is in the same order as my original species names output from `$tip.labels`. I want to preserve my tree topology, just trying to update my phylogeny with new taxonomic names.

output from $tip.labels:

```
old_taxonomic_names
old_species_name_1
old_species_name_2
old_species_name_3
...
```

input with updated taxonomy:

```
new_taxonomic_names
new_species_name_1
new_species_name_2
new_species_name_3
...
```

Comment: Can you provide some data and the expected output? Am I correct in my understanding that you want to preserve the tree topology and just swap the tip labels?

Comment: yes, preserve tree topology and just swap tip labels

Comment: Then why not just directly write the new species list to the tip labels? It should work (you'd just have to replot the tree).

Comment: How do I do that? I updated my post

Comment: Please refer to the answer I posted.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following toy example:

```
library("ape")

orig_tiplabels <- c("Alice", "Bob", "Cindy")
orig_tree <- rtree(n = 3, tip.label = orig_tiplabels)
plot(orig_tree)

new_tiplabels <- c("Debbie", "Elrond", "Frank")
orig_tree$tip.label <- new_tiplabels
plot(orig_tree)
```

`orig_tree` is the following tree:
[image: .]

Since we only want to change the tip labels, we can simply update the `$tip.label` attribute directly. This yields us a "new" tree with updated tip labels, but the topology preserved, as shown below.
[image]

This will work as long as the number of new labels is the same as the number of existing labels (in the tree), and the same tree object is used.

Comment: Don't see why you really need your "too long for a comment" disclaimer, this seems to be a perfectly reasonable answer ...  A solution with `match()` might be slightly safer since it doesn't rely on knowing/looking up the order of tips ...

Comment: Mainly because of the images. Never used `match()` before, could you perhaps show me how that'd be done?

Comment: My point is that I don't think you need the disclaimer. `new_tree <- orig_tree; new_tree$tip.label <- new_tiplabels[match(orig_tree$tip.label,orig_tiplabels)]; par(mfrow=c(1,2));  plot(orig_tree); plot(new_tree)`

Comment: I have a new, but related, post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57680924/changing-tip-labels-for-a-multiphylo-object