# Changing tip labels for a multiphylo object

Tags: r, phylogeny

The answer and question is related to this post: [Change tip labels in phylogeny in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547769/change-tip-labels-in-phylogeny-in-r). I have old tip labels I want to replace with new tip labels because of taxonomic changes. How would I do this with a multiPhylo object in R? I have a random distribution of trees from the posterior I would like to update with new taxonomic names.

Answer (score 3):

`multiPhylo` objects are simply lists of `phylo` objects so the best way to modify them is to use `lapply`.

First you should define the function allowing to rename tips

```
## Function for renaming tips
rename.tips.phylo <- function(tree, names) {
    tree$tip.label <- names
    return(tree)
}
```

You can then apply it to as many trees as you'd like:

```
## Generating 50 random 5 tips trees
random_trees <- rmtree(50, 5)

## Renaming all the tips
random_trees_renamed <- lapply(random_trees, rename.tips.phylo,
                               names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
```

However, the output will be a list so you'll have to manually switch the class back to `multiPhylo`:

```
## Class of the original object
class(random_trees)
#[1] "multiPhylo"

## Class of the renamed trees
class(random_trees_renamed)
#[1] "list"

## Changing the class
class(random_trees_renamed) <- "multiPhylo"
class(random_trees_renamed)
#[1] "multiPhylo"
```

And now all your tip labels have been renamed:

```
## First tree
random_trees_renamed[[1]]$tip.label
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
## 42nd tree
random_trees_renamed[[42]]$tip.label
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

Comment: One addition to this, it needs a vector to tell which are the old names and which are the new. I'd replace one line in the function with tree$tip.label <- new_names[match(tree$tip.label,old_names)], with new_names and old_names being columns with the taxon names. This way you don't have to worry about order.